# loading js dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm conditionally loading a script if the browser is IE8. I'm using jquery's .getScript function because I need to run something after the script is loaded. The problem is in the format of the URL. I've got it working when downloading the script that's on my hard drive directory but I can't get it to work when loading the script from a site.

This is what I have, I'm sure it's a simple fix but I'm not getting it to work:

```
 $.getScript("https://github.com/malsup/corner/blob/master/jquery.corner.js", function () { 
  //does something here
});
```

Thanks for your fix.

Comment: seams the problem in the https

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are requesting the actual formatted github page ... so you get back html..

use

```
$.getScript("https://raw.github.com/malsup/corner/master/jquery.corner.js", function () { 
  //does something here
});
```

(*changed the url to the correct one..*)

There is a link `Raw` on the heading bar above the formatted code. Click it to get to the raw file..

---

The safe url is `http://malsup.github.com/jquery.corner.js`

Comment: ok, in the //does something here line, I added an alert line that pops when the script is loaded. Indeed, your solution works to load the script because the alert popup is triggered as expected. However, when I do $('#MyDiv').corner('12px'); the script executes fine when I load it from my loacal machine but not when I load it from the external site. It's the same script. What could be the problem?

Comment: IE is showing in the console the following:  SEC7112: Script from https://raw.github.com/malsup/malsup.github.com/master/jquery.corner.js?_=1310609373311 was blocked due to mime type mismatch 
What's the problem?

Comment: @frenchie, it works fine for me at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/8Y6Rj/ Make sure you target the correct element, and that the element has border or background so you can see the effect..

Comment: Yes, it works in chrome but not in IE, which is the browser that needs to use this plugin. What a crap IE is :) See above, it has to do with the MIME type.

Comment: @frenchie, updated answer with Url with correct mime type. example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/8Y6Rj/1/